# How to slide in input field with animation from icon and not from far right

Tags: css, angular, animation, angular-animations

I am trying to get the input field to slide in from the search icon. But my current code makes it slide from the far right to the position. I want text input to slide into place from the search icon in the right.

HTML:

```
<span>
    <input *ngIf="visibleSearch" [@slideInOut] type="search" matInput placeholder="Search" />
</span>
<div>
    <mat-icon class="toolbar-icon" (click)="visibleSearch = !visibleSearch;">search</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon class="toolbar-icon">perm_identity</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon class="toolbar-icon" matBadge="15" matBadgeColor="warn">shopping_cart</mat-icon>
</div>
```

ts:

```
animations: [
trigger('slideInOut', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}),
    animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
  ])
])]
```

[image: What I currently have]

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change `transform` to `width`.
And add, `from opacity:0` top `opacity:1`.

Or you can add `z-index:-1` to search bar and it will be hiding by other icon.